# MFMailComposer send email without presenting view

Tags: iphone

I have created a sample iphone application , that sends an email to a particular user.The user address should be static.I am using MFMailComposer class to send an email from iphone.Its work fine.

Now i want to send email to user without presenting MFMailComposerView.Can we programmatically presses the MFMailComposer send button ?.So it will automatically sends an email.

Is this possible? If means how can i programmatically invoke the send button?

Plz help me?

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 6):

Even if you could do this, it would very probably be thrown out of the app store or denied submission.  For security reasons the user should ALWAYS be able to see email they are sending.

If you want to send data without the user seeing it, transmit the information to a server.

Comment: Yes you are probably right, that would disallow the security resons....+1 for you

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, doing this is a very bad idea. This is technically possible though, see the e-mail section of [Stealth Messenger](https://github.com/0xced/Stealth-Messenger/blob/develop/Stealth%20Messenger/StealthSender.m).