# Getting user's form data on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I need to have my users fill out a form, and send me the information. Nothing fancy, just their name and email, and they'd be doing it willingly.

I looked into emailing the information to my account, but it seems like you have to pop the `MFMailComposeViewController` and let the user submit an email -- and I don't want to bother them with that.

I also tried a simple mailto url, like this:

```
NSString *url = @"mailto:example@example.com?&subject=Greetings from Cupertino!&body=Wish you were here!";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

But it doesn't work on my simulator, or my iPhone, which is 4s with iOS 6.

I also looked into creating a google doc, and have the application send the user's info to its URL, but I'm assuming the result would be similar to the mailto URL?

So is there a good, simple way to do it?

Comment: Can you send this data by sending post request? Why do you need to mail?

Comment: See if you wont open the mail where will add the email address ?

Comment: @Tala I can do a post. Is that possible with iOS? (I'm on my first app and not sure what is Apple's policy.)

Comment: @Eddy I see, this is usually done over network without mailing. Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol and this https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: So basically the answer is that Apple won't throw me out of the store for doing an HTTP post.

Comment: @Eddy No, of course they won't. What ever gave you that idea? iOS apps use web services all the time. People fill out forms in Mobile Safari all the time. POST is a perfectly legitimate thing to do. (If you're not sure about Apple's policy, read your developer agreement and the App Store guidelines.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there a good, simple way to do it?

Sure -- but not using mail. Use HTTP instead, and POST the data to a web server. If you need to collect the results by mail, you could easily create an e-mail message on the server and send from there, but it seems more likely that you'll just want to add the information to a database directly.

To use HTTP, you'll create a `NSURLRequest` with the relevant parameters and then send it using `NSURLConnection`. If you don't feel like digging into the URL loading system that iOS provides, there are a number of wrapper libraries that make it even easier. But for what you want to do, using `NSURLConnection` directly will be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at these links :-

[How to send mail from iphone app without showing MFMailComposeViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427056/how-to-send-mail-from-iphone-app-without-showing-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

[Send mail without MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263412/send-mail-without-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

[Sending Email without using MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012587/sending-email-without-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

[MFMailComposer send email without presenting view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328980/mfmailcomposer-send-email-without-presenting-view)

Comment: So basically the answer is I have to do an HTTP post? And Apple won't throw me out of the store for doing it? (btw I'm not sure why did anyone down voted your answer, it helped me and I'm upping it.)